# find files on remote machine

Tags: linux, sed, awk, find, command

Hi i am trying to execute the following command on a remote machine how do i do this

```
ssh login.com find /nfs/repo/ -name ".user_repo.log" | \
  xargs cat | awk '{$NF=""; print $0}' |               \
  sed "1i Owner RepoName CreatedDate" | column -t
```

I get the following error message

```
 cat: /nfs/repo/new1/info/.user_repo.log: No such file or directory
 cat: /nfs/repo/new2/info/.user_repo.log: No such file or directory
```

cat command is trying to find file on the local system while these files are present on the remote machine.How do i handle this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do:

```
ssh host command1 | command2
```

Then the shell will break at the pipe, so you'll get "ssh host command1" run as one command (i.e. remotely), and then "command2" run as another command (i.e., locally.) You can force all the commands to run remotely by enclosing in quotes:

```
ssh host "command1 | command2"
```

Note, since you already have quotes in the command, you might have to get creative with escaping.

Or, you might put all those commands in a short shell script and then just run the script:

```
ssh host myscript.sh
```

Comment: +1 for the shellscript, this seems to be the only sane way to do it.